# Unexpected (T_STRING) on line 1 - CodeIgniter - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a very basic Controller, it simply loads some models and prepare the view.
It works fine on my local host (XAMPP), but when I upload it to HostGator sever i get

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'dashboard' (T_STRING) in /home3/fady1234/public_html/dubai/application/controllers/dashboard.php on line 1

This is the code:

```
<?php
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $data = array();
        $this->load->model('admin_m');
        $this->security_m->checkAdminSession();
        $this->load->model('settings_m');
        $this->load->model('property_m');
        $this->load->model('community_m');
        $this->load->model('service_m');
        $this->load->model('complains_m');
        $this->load->model('user_m');
        $this->load->model('announcment_m');
        $this->load->model('news_m');
    }
    public function index(){
        $data['menu'] = 1;
        $data['settings'] = $this->settings_m->get(null, null);
        $data['property'] = $this->property_m->count();
        $data['community'] = $this->community_m->count();
        $data['service'] = $this->service_m->count();
        $data['complains'] = $this->complains_m->count();
        $data['users'] = $this->user_m->count();
        $data['announcments'] = $this->announcment_m->count();
        $data['news'] = $this->news_m->count();        
        $data['subview'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/header' , $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main');
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer' , $data);
    }
    public function modal(){
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal' , $this->data);
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help in advance, i know it's common and i tried every resource i could find on the web but it's not working.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: seems to me like your file might be coded wrongly... did you make sure your document is UTF-8?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. Are you uploading the actual file to the server or just copy+pasting the code from your file to another file on the server? If you're uploading the file itself, it may(and this is a wild guess) have encoding issues.

Comment: You said you uploaded your file. Did you use FTP? Did it upload as binary or ASCII?

Comment: In the attached code there is no reason for such an error. You should check other files loaded in that request, like the view/layout/model files. This type of error usually means a quote/double-quote is missing or improperly escaped somewhere.

Comment: @Icewind I posted the full error message

Comment: @AndreiP. How to check for encoding errors?

Comment: @Machavity I use filezilla and it is set to Auto

Comment: @AhmedSaad Try forcing it to use ASCII and see if it makes a difference